# Are command line commands the same between Raspbian and Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, raspbian

So I currently want to make a prototype for my server I'm making and I'd like to use raspberry Pis for it and later on using a proper computer(s) to run the server. I was just wandering if all the scripts I run on the Raspberry Pi on the Raspbian wheezy OS will work the same on ubuntu. Would it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On such a generic level, the answer has to be "no" - simply because the two different OS have potentially different versions of certain packages, different architectures for e.g. startup-scripts, and also a different set of services running etc....

So depending on what you do, you will have to adapt to the new OS.

Of course limited to the scope of certain commands, the answer could be yes.